# Nodejs convert date format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, datetime

I have the mongodb date format that is like:

```
2020-07-22T00: 48: 02.415 + 00: 00
```

which I want to convert to this format:

```
2020-07-22T00: 48: 02.4150000
```

Notice that the difference is just in removing  "+" and ":" symbols in the last 7 numbers.

I would like to implement a function or find a way to convert this date format.

Comment: Is the variable a `Date` object?

Comment: Yes, It is a date object